# If fetched data from MySql is smaller than *number*, show this, else show something else?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Hi Masters of Web Programing.
I've got this code:

```
<?PHP

$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'dbname';
$db_host = 'localhost';
if(mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass)) {
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS smsads(id bigint unsigned primary key auto_increment, link varchar(255), fromnum varchar(60))");
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smsads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 36");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {

        if ($res>=36){

        $http_link = $row->link;
        $root_link = strpos($http_link, '/');
            if ($root_link !== false) {
            $before = substr($http_link, 0, $root_link);
        }

        echo "<div id=\"banner\"><a href=\"http://{$before}\" alt=\"{$before}\" title=\"{$before}\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://{$http_link}\" /></a></div>";
    }
        else {
            echo $res . "<div id=\"banner\"></div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

As we can see, the number of fetched rows are limited to 36. How to make if rows are smaller than 36, to show the existing ones plus adding something else for each one until 36?
For example this is a script for pixel advertisement, and I want to visualize the existing pixels (for example, I have 20 inserted pixels), and to show empty boxes into other places that are empty (total 36 places - 20 already placed items = 16 empty places) until the count reaches total 36 boxes.

As you can see, I tried with "If", "else", but it always shows only empty boxes (becouse I don't know how to tell it to show RESULTS + empty boxes)...

Comment: What does "if ($res>=36)" in your opinion?

Comment: Well, If the count is 36 or more, to show only existing pixels... 
Else, If the count is smaller than 36, to show existing pixels plus blank boxes (<div id="banner"> is defined id from css) for each one place until it reaches total 36 boxes...
I don't know, I tried things, hoping it's gonna work...

Comment: But: $res is a query resource, not a count?

Comment: Yes... I can see that there is no sense in this. I just tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite everything into a for loop, it also makes everything a bit easier to understand:

```
for($cnt = 0; $cnt < 36; $cnt++){
    if($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
        // In here you should have the code for the boxes to be filled.
        $http_link = $row->link;
        $root_link = strpos($http_link, '/');
        if ($root_link !== false) {
            $before = substr($http_link, 0, $root_link);
        }
        echo "<div id=\"banner\"><a href=\"http://{$before}\" alt=\"{$before}\" title=\"{$before}\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://{$http_link}\" /></a></div>";
    }else{
        // In here you should have the code for the empty boxes
        echo "<div id=\"banner\"></div>";
    }
}
```

This will always iterate through the loop 36 times, those times it will find a row it will print the row, otherwise it will print the empty banner tag.

Comment: Yes, It works... but the mine problem is still there - it shows only empty boxes, not the fetched ones plus empty boxes...

Comment: It should. Since $row will be an object if it finds a fetched box, everything within that block should be executed (you need to populate the boxes there). If it is not, it you need to fill it up in the else.

I'll rewrite it in another way to try to make it clearer

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. It's working just great!
Now I'm starting to observe the code that you wrote because I want to know exactly how it works :)) Thanks I'm appreciated!

Comment: the first example won't work since the `++$cnt < 36` won't be evaluated until `mysql_fetch_object` starts returning false, which means you'll get *up to* 36 filled rows and then 36 empty rows. The second example is better though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($res) >= 36) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the code that executes if the if statement is true?